# AttributeError: 'TikTokApi' object has no attribute 'width'

Tags: python, python-3.x, api, tiktok

I'm trying to use the library TikTokApi to download TikTok data but when I call any method, it throws:

```
AttributeError: 'TikTokApi' object has no attribute 'width'
```

Here is an example of the code I'm running:

```
from TikTokApi import TikTokApi
api = TikTokApi.get_instance(use_selenium=True)
n_videos = 100
username = 'washingtonpost'
user_videos = api.byUsername(username, count=n_videos)
```

Same happens if I try this one https://github.com/davidteather/TikTok-Api/blob/master/examples/getAUsersVideos.py

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have the same problem. As David said, this error means that python-playwright or selenium is not launching correctly.
What I did is

1. Check the version of your chrome
   Right upper corner  -> help -> About Google Chrome
2. Download the chromedriver from [chromedriver](https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads)!
3. let your API find the driver

```
api = TikTokApi.get_instance(use_selenium=True, executablePath="/path/to/chromedriver")
```

Answer (score 1):

Also having the same issue.
You can bypass this issue by calling the `api.getUser` method and then iterate on the results that way.

Comment: Thank you! This works very well as a workaround!

Comment: getUser works, but it only returns 6 videos thou

Answer (score 1):

I'm the author of TikTokApi, this error means that python-playwright or selenium is not launching correctly. I recommend following the respective quickstart guides and to see if that throws any more detailed issues.